# Swipe to Cancel intstead of delete in UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using the following code to show a delete button when the user swipes the `tableview` cell. I want to write Cancel instead of Delete in this button, how can i achieve this functionality??

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //remove the deleted object from your data source.
    //If you're data source is an NSMutableArray, do this
    [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Delete button On Editing in UITableView Cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615469/custom-delete-button-on-editing-in-uitableview-cell)

Comment: It appears that you would like to keep the functionality, but display a different button. In this case, scroll to the highest-voted answer to see how you can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the title of the button to "Cancel", then just implement the `-tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:` method in your table view's delegate.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Cancel";
}
```