# Change delete button title in UITableView editing mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When I call `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]`, the tableview goes into editing mode. When I press on the round minus button, the delete button appears. I would like to change the title of this delete button. How can I do that?

Comment: you just want to change title for delete button? or completely delete button?

Comment: @FahimParkar The question clearly states that they want to change the title.

Comment: @rmaddy : I understand, but usually all ask for button design as the one apple have is ugly...

Comment: if you want design to be changed of delete button, follow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615469/custom-delete-button-on-editing-in-uitableview-cell, [google result](https://www.google.com.kw/search?q=uitableview+custom+delete+button&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW503KW503&oq=uitableview+custom+delete+button&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i65.4395j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easily done using the proper `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return @"CustomLabel";
}
```

Comment: can we change titleForInsert button?