# UITableViewCell change font of delete row button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, fonts

Is it possible to customise the font of the delete button in a `UITableView` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the delete button of [`UITableViewCell`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/) the system font is used. So if you want to change the system font in your app just override [`-systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize):

Create category `UIFont+System` and place this code inside `.m`

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"NameOfYourFont" size:fontSize];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511432/3981769)

You could use an image with the font you want and then set the button to this image. May be problematic if you have different languages

Answer (score -1):

You can take advantage of

```
UIButton * buttonAppearance = [UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[YourCustomCell class]]];
[buttonAppearance setAttributedTitle: attributedString forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Note: This will set the title to all the buttons in your cells. You can then change it if required.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working in iOS 11. not sure if it worked prior