# Swift : Changing the appearance of the delete button on a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have followed [Custom Delete button On Editing in UITableView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615469/custom-delete-button-on-editing-in-uitableview-cell) about hiding the delete button that appears on a swipe to delete cell.

I have gone 3 levels down in the view stack and can't find the delete button, I basically need to change the height of it.

Has anyone been able to do this? **What I want to actually achieve is changing the height of it.**

```
 override func willTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
        super.willTransitionToState(state)

        if state == UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask
        {
            for subview in self.subviews as [UIView]
            {
                subview.hidden = true;
                // ios 8
                for subview2 in subview.subviews as [UIView]
                {
                    subview2.hidden = true;
                    //print(getName(subview2.classForCoder))
                }

            }
        }
    }
```