# Change to delete Default Icon of UITableViewcell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change the image of the delete button that is displayed in the `TableViewCell`.

[image]

I would like to change the image of this button, not the one on the right.

Comment: Can you post your code, your problem is unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change UITableView delete image swit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628940/change-uitableview-delete-image-swit)

Comment: You can find you answer here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603359/change-default-icon-for-moving-cells-in-uitableview