# Add Custom Image instead of TableView delete red button - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can add my custom image instead of the red default delete button when I slide my tableView cell. Thanks in advance and I am using Swift!

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12511432/1241782

Comment: @Mike I got it to finally work. Now I need help sizing it to fit perfect inside the cell. At the moment only a piece is showing. Any clue how to do that in Swift? I am pretty new at this. Thanks!