# How to resize a UITableViewRowAction to fit custom sized tableViewCell? - Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, resize, xcode8, uitableviewrowaction

In my app I customized my `TableViewCell` to display like a card. I also implemented custom `UITableViewRowActions` for those cells. However the actions look weird because I added a layer to make the cell look like a floating card.

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlceU.png)
And here's my code for my `cellForRowAt` function.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "someCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.delegate = self

        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

        let whiteRoundedView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: cell.frame.size.height - 20))
        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9])
        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)

        cell.updateCell()
        return cell
    }
```

And my `UITableViewRowAction` function. Forewarning: I am using this [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/jerkoch/SwipeCellKit) repository

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        if orientation == .left {
            guard isSwipeRightEnabled else { return nil }
            let completeAction = SwipeAction(style: .default, title: "Complete") { (action, index) in
                print("complete!")

            }
            completeAction.backgroundColor = .green
            return [completeAction]
        } else {
            let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, index) in
                print("delete")
            }
            return [deleteAction]
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to resize the `UITableViewRowAction` to fit that mold of the cell?

Comment: Hope this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12511432/1931317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible without making some changes to the framework.

I do have plans to add some methods to `SwipeTableViewCellDelegate` which would expose each `UIButton` just before being displayed, and as swiping continues to occur. I imagine that would give you enough flexibility to achieve your layout.

This shouldn't be too hard to do on your own fork in the meantime. Specifically, look at `SwipeTableViewCell`, inside the `configureActionView` method. It creates the `SwipeActionsView` which has a `buttons` property containing the swipe `UIButton` subclass.  You just need to expose those to your app.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still looking for a solution in 2019, you can use invisible unicode character to set the width.

```
UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDestructive title:@"\u2060\t\t\t\u2060" handler: [self handler]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your viewDidLoad() and it will create a custom row accordingly

tableView.rowHeight = 80.0