# Slide to delete with similar design to iOS 10+ Notifications slide to delete in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, slide, uitableviewrowaction

How can I make a tableviewcell's slide to delete look like the slide to delete for iOS notifications (fade in and don't touch edge of the screen). I  will only have the delete button so I don't need multiple buttons. I would like it to delete upon a full swipe just like the notifications.

Here's a photo of the wanted result with 2 buttons (I only want 1):

[image: iOS notification swipe to delete]

The current code I have written only sets the editing style to delete. I have tried using `UIContextualAction` but I believe I can only set the style, background color, and/or image.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("delete")
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like with my current code:[image: What I currently have]

Comment: Morning and welcome to SO! :) Remember to include some code samples within your question.

Comment: Thanks! I just added my code above. I know it's not much and I haven't been able to find pretty much anything to help me. I'm just looking for ideas or solutions to ways to achieve a similar result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615469/custom-delete-button-on-editing-in-uitableview-cell

Comment: You are better off creating the entire UI yourself instead of trying to customise the Delete button OS provides

Comment: Thanks for the link. For the most part a lot of the code is meant for iOS 3-4 and one answer for iOS 7. I'm trying to convert some of their code to swift and make the necessary changes for iOS 11 but I'm still not getting far.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a UIView inside the `UITableViewCell`, with a red background, and a label inside the `UIView` with the text of delete. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm trying to get the result in the first photo not the second. I also want the clear button to be interactive by sliding over and clearing just like in the iOS Notification Center.